# Erlang process event error

Tags: process, erlang

I'm basically following the tutorial on this site [Learn you some Erlang:Designing a concurrent application](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/designing-a-concurrent-application#understanding-the-problem) and I tried to run the code below with the following commands and got an error on line 48. I did turn off my firewall just in case that was the problem but no luck. I'm on windows xp SP3.

9> c(event).

{ok,event}

10> f().

ok

11> event:start("Event",0).

=ERROR REPORT==== 9-Feb-2013::15:05:07 ===
Error in process <0.61.0> with exit value: {function_clause,[{event,time_to_go,[0],[{file,"event.erl"},{line,48}]},{event,init,3,[{file,"event.erl"},{line,31}]}]}

<0.61.0>

12>

```
-module(event).
-export([start/2, start_link/2, cancel/1]).
-export([init/3, loop/1]).
-record(state, {server,
                name="",
                to_go=0}).

%%% Public interface
start(EventName, DateTime) ->
    spawn(?MODULE, init, [self(), EventName, DateTime]).

start_link(EventName, DateTime) ->
    spawn_link(?MODULE, init, [self(), EventName, DateTime]).

cancel(Pid) ->
    %% Monitor in case the process is already dead
    Ref = erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
    Pid ! {self(), Ref, cancel},
    receive
        {Ref, ok} ->
            erlang:demonitor(Ref, [flush]),
            ok;
        {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, _Reason} ->
            ok
    end.

%%% Event's innards
init(Server, EventName, DateTime) ->
    loop(#state{server=Server,
                name=EventName,
                to_go=time_to_go(DateTime)}).

%% Loop uses a list for times in order to go around the ~49 days limit
%% on timeouts.
loop(S = #state{server=Server, to_go=[T|Next]}) ->
    receive
        {Server, Ref, cancel} ->
            Server ! {Ref, ok}
    after T*1000 ->
        if Next =:= [] ->
            Server ! {done, S#state.name};
           Next =/= [] ->
            loop(S#state{to_go=Next})
        end
    end.

%%% private functions
time_to_go(TimeOut={{_,_,_}, {_,_,_}}) ->
    Now = calendar:local_time(),
    ToGo = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(TimeOut) -
           calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(Now),
    Secs = if ToGo > 0  -> ToGo;
              ToGo =< 0 -> 0
           end,
    normalize(Secs).

%% Because Erlang is limited to about 49 days (49*24*60*60*1000) in
%% milliseconds, the following function is used
normalize(N) ->
    Limit = 49*24*60*60,
    [N rem Limit | lists:duplicate(N div Limit, Limit)].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's running purely locally on your machine so the firewall will not affect it.

The problem is the second argument you gave when you started it `event:start("Event",0).`

The error reason:

```
{function_clause,[{event,time_to_go,[0],[{file,"event.erl"},{line,48}]},{event,init,3,[{file,"event.erl"},{line,31}]}]}
```

says that it is a `function_clause` error which means that there was no clause in the function definition which matched the arguments. It also tells you that it was the function `event:time_to_go/1` on line 48 which failed and that it was called with the argument `0`.

It you look at the function `time_to_go/` you will see that it expects its argument to be a tuple of 2 elements where each element is a tuple of 3 elements:

```
time_to_go(TimeOut={{_,_,_}, {_,_,_}}) ->
```

The structure of this argument is `{{Year,Month,Day},{Hour,Minute,Second}}`. If you follow this argument backwards you that `time_to_go/` is called from `init/3` where the argument to `time_to_go/1`, `DateTime`, is the 3rd argument to `init/3`. Almost there now. Now `init/3` is the function which the process spawned in `start/2` (and start_link/2`) and the 3rd argument to`init/3`is the second argument to`start/2`.

So when you call `event:start("Event",0).` it is the `0` here which is passed into the call `time_to_go/1` function in the new peocess. And the format is wrong. You should be calling it with something like `event:start("Event", {{2013,3,24},{17,53,62}}).`

Comment: That was something I did think (that the arguments I passed were wrong) but I was blindly following the tutorial on the site and if you look you'll notice he did not get any error running it whatsoever?? Thanks it works now!

Comment: @lost_with_coding I checked the book and to me it looks like the call with `0` is for the first version where the time is seconds(?). As far as I could see he gave no example of a call for the second version with the date/time tuples. Which he should have. If I read it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To add background to rvirding's answer, you get the error because the
 example works up until the final code snippet as far
as I know. The `normalize` function is used first, which deals with the
problem. Then the paragraph right after the example in the question
above, the text says:

> And it works! The last thing annoying with the event module is that we
>   have to input the time left in seconds. It would be much better if we
>   could use a standard format such as Erlang's datetime (`{{Year, Month,
>   Day}, {Hour, Minute, Second}}`). Just add the following function that
>   will calculate the difference between the current time on your
>   computer and the delay you inserted:

The next snippet introduces the code bit that takes only a date/time and
changes it to the final time left.

I could not easily link to all transitional versions of the file, which
is why trying the linked file directly with the example doesn't work
super easily in this case. If the code is followed step by step, snippet
by snippet, everything should work fine. Sorry for the confusion.