# erlang spawn process error?

Tags: process, erlang, spawn

I'm following [this tutorial](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/designing-a-concurrent-application) and I tried to compile the event.erl and run it according to

```
6> c(event).
{ok,event}
7> rr(event, state).
[state]
8> spawn(event, loop, [#state{server=self(), name="test", to_go=5}]).
<0.60.0>
9> flush().
ok
10> flush().
Shell got {done,"test"}
ok
11> Pid = spawn(event, loop, [#state{server=self(), name="test", to_go=500}]).
<0.64.0>
12> ReplyRef = make_ref().
#Ref<0.0.0.210>
13> Pid ! {self(), ReplyRef, cancel}.
{<0.50.0>,#Ref<0.0.0.210>,cancel}
14> flush().
Shell got {#Ref<0.0.0.210>,ok}
ok
```

But I cannot seem to get past step 8 because I get this error instead.

```
7> spawn(event, loop, [#state{server=self(), name="test", to_go=5}]).

=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Feb-2013::11:14:38 ===
Error in process <0.51.0> with exit value: {function_clause,[{event,loop,[{state,<0.32.0>,"test",5}],[{file,"event.erl"},{line,35}]}]}

<0.51.0>
```

The following is event.erl

```
-module(event).
-export([start/2, start_link/2, cancel/1]).
-export([init/3, loop/1]).
-record(state, {server,
                name="",
                to_go=0}).

%%% Public interface
start(EventName, DateTime) ->
    spawn(?MODULE, init, [self(), EventName, DateTime]).

start_link(EventName, DateTime) ->
    spawn_link(?MODULE, init, [self(), EventName, DateTime]).

cancel(Pid) ->
    %% Monitor in case the process is already dead
    Ref = erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
    Pid ! {self(), Ref, cancel},
    receive
        {Ref, ok} ->
            erlang:demonitor(Ref, [flush]),
            ok;
        {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, _Reason} ->
            ok
    end.

%%% Event's innards
init(Server, EventName, DateTime) ->
    loop(#state{server=Server,
                name=EventName,
                to_go=time_to_go(DateTime)}).

%% Loop uses a list for times in order to go around the ~49 days limit
%% on timeouts.
loop(S = #state{server=Server, to_go=[T|Next]}) ->
    receive
        {Server, Ref, cancel} ->
            Server ! {Ref, ok}
    after T*1000 ->
        if Next =:= [] ->
            Server ! {done, S#state.name};
           Next =/= [] ->
            loop(S#state{to_go=Next})
        end
    end.

%%% private functions
time_to_go(TimeOut={{_,_,_}, {_,_,_}}) ->
    Now = calendar:local_time(),
    ToGo = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(TimeOut) -
           calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(Now),
    Secs = if ToGo > 0  -> ToGo;
              ToGo =< 0 -> 0
           end,
    normalize(Secs).

%% Because Erlang is limited to about 49 days (49*24*60*60*1000) in
%% milliseconds, the following function is used
normalize(N) ->
    Limit = 49*24*60*60,
    [N rem Limit | lists:duplicate(N div Limit, Limit)].
```

EDIT: I tried to change the function loop by adding an argument from this

```
loop(S = #state{server=Server, to_go=[T|Next]}) ->

to this 

loop(S = #state{server=Server,name=EventName, to_go=[T|Next]}) ->
```

and it still compiles but it doesnt work, same error... I thought maybe the tuples didn't match. It then only evolves down to the argument `to_go=[T|Next]}` being incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same problem as in [Erlang process event error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791717/erlang-process-event-error). The `start/2`, `start_link/2` and `time_to_go/1` functions expects a time argument of the form `{{Year,Month,Day},{Hour,Minute,Second}}` which is why they fail when you call them with `5`. The `loop/1` function expects the `to_go` field of `#state{}` to be a list of **integers** which it interprets as seconds and will wait for the total time by doing a `receive...after` for each one. The goal of this server is to be able to wait for a longer period of time than Erlang directly can do in a `receive...after`.

The `time_to_go/1` function is calculating the number of seconds between now and the date/time entered as argument and then breaking that down into a list of seconds of which none are greater than the maximum size `receive...after` can handle.

Comment: So essentially the time_to_go function needs a huge rewrite in order to function properly. Oh well I don't feel like doing that. But yeah thanks, that explains the reason for the crash well enough for me to understand the problem.

Comment: @lost_with_coding no it is just that in the book the example call is before it is changed to use a new type of argument.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that your loop/1 clause unpacks the #state parameter such that to_go is pattern-matched to a list (i.e., to_go = [T|Next]). However, you pass in a 5 (to_go=5) which will fail to match [T | Next] therefore the loop/1 will not match and you will have no function clause which matches

```
loop(#state{server=self(), name="test", to_go=5})
```

Comment: You could fix this by adding a function clause to loop like: `loop(S = #state{to_go = N}) when is_number(N) -> loop(S#state{to_go = normalize(N)});`

Comment: @Soup, your solution seems vague. I first tried to simply remove the old loop function and replace it with yours but that didn't work and then I tried to replace loop(S = #state{to_go = N}) when is_number(N) -> with this loop(S = #state{to_go = N}) when is_number(N) -> and also this part  loop(S#state{to_go=Next}) with  loop(S#state{to_go = normalize(N)}); but those two couldn't compile. I'll admit I'm new to this language and I'm trying to learn it.

Comment: So you shouldn't *replace* the function with my solution, you should *add* my solution to your function. In the end it should look like this: `loop(S = #state{to_go = N}) when is_integer(N) -> loop(S#state{to_go = normalize(N)}); loop(S = #state{server = Server, to_go = [T|Next]) -> YOUR_CODE_HERE.` For a solid breakdown on function clauses and what they mean, go here: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions

Comment: @Soup, you must be kidding me like this?                          loop(S = #state{to_go = N}) when is_integer(N) -> 
loop(S#state{to_go = normalize(N)});
loop(S = #state{server=Server, to_go=[T|Next]}) ->
    receive
        {Server, Ref, cancel} ->
            Server ! {Ref, ok}
    after T*1000 ->
        if Next =:= [] ->
            Server ! {done, S#state.name};
           Next =/= [] ->
            loop(S#state{to_go=Next})
        end
    end.

Comment: @lost_with_coding - No. I'm not kidding you. Take a look at that site (http://learnyousomeerlang.com/). Erlang is very different.

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
8> spawn(event, loop, [#state{server=self(), name="test", to_go=5}]).
```

applies to an earlier version of the code, as it's being developed throughout the tutorial. If I'm reading it correctly, this should be the correct call:

```
19> event:start("Event", 0).
```

Comment: I tried doing this instead of step eight and got another error instead; I'm not sure what init means in the spawn process, its a function that takes the arguments for Server, EventName and DateTime, its really confusing : 8> event:start("Event", 0).

=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Feb-2013::12:22:41 ===
Error in process <0.53.0> with exit value: {function_clause,[{event,time_to_go,[0],[{file,"event.erl"},{line,48}]},{event,init,3,[{file,"event.erl"},{line,31}]}]}

<0.53.0>

Comment: Ah, that's from a later modification of `time_to_go` :) This version takes a datetime instead of an integer, so you'd call `event:start("Event", {{2013, 2, 14}, {22, 53, 0}})` instead.  (Or just use the return value of `erlang:localtime()`.)

Comment: event:start("Event", {{2013, 2, 14}, {22, 53, 0}}).  Worked! thanks.